# Is there an equivalent of the matlab 'idealfilter' for Python in Scipy (or other libraries)?

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, scipy, dct

I am looking for an equivalent of the time series [idealfilter](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeseries.idealfilter.html) that is implemented in Matlab, for Python.

My goal is to implement an ideal filter using Discrete Cosine Transform as is used in the [Eulerian Video Magnification paper](http://people.csail.mit.edu/mrub/vidmag/) in Python in order to obtain the heartbeat of a human being from standard video. I am using their video as my input and I have implemented the bandpass filter method, but I have not been able to find an idealfilter method to use in my script.

They state that they implement an ideal filter using DCT from 0.83 - 1.0Hz.

My problem is that the idealfilter in Matlab takes in as input the cutoff frequencies, but I don't think it is implemented with dct.

In contrast, the DCT filter found in scipy.fftpack does not take in as input the frequency cutoffs.

If I have to use these in some type of succession please let me know.

If such a function equivalent exists I would like to attempt to use it in order to see if it yields similar results to what they have obtained.

Answer (score 1):

Non-causal means that your filter depends on future inputs. 
DCT is a transform, not a filter. You want a filter.

You want to apply a bandpass filter to your data within the range you specified, so I would use a butterworth filter.

Here is some example code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12233959/1097117

The trickiest part of all of this is getting everything in terms of your Nyquist frequency.

Answer (score 0):

I maybe worth to have a look to the [time series analysis module of the statsmodel library.](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/tsa.html#other-time-series-filters) This module implements several time series filters, including the Hodrick-Prescott filter, which I *think* is non-causal.