# 20hz-20000hz Butterworth filtering exploding

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, filtering, signal-processing

I want to filter out everything outside 20 Hz - 20000 Hz. I'm using a Butterworth filter:

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
from scipy import signal
import numpy

sr, x = wavfile.read('sweep.wav')
nyq = 0.5 * sr
b, a = signal.butter(5, [20.0 / nyq, 20000.0 / nyq], btype='band')

x = signal.lfilter(b, a, x)
x = numpy.float32(x)
x /= numpy.max(numpy.abs(x))
wavfile.write('b.wav', sr, x)
```

I've noticed that it works with a 44.1 khz file, but **not with a 96 khz WAV file** ([demo file here](http://gget.it/ooeln2hi/sweep.wav)) (it's not an audio I/O problem): the output is either blank (silence) or exploding (with some other input wav files).

1) Is there something that makes that the Butterworth filters don't work with a bandpass [b1, b2] where b2 < 0.5 ?

2) **More generally, how would you do a filtering to keep only 20 - 20000Hz with Python / scipy?** (no other external library)

Comment: Wrong stack.  Try dsp.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Scipy is an external library.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`scipy.signal.butter` is generating an unstable filter:

```
In [17]: z, p, k = signal.tf2zpk(b, a)

In [18]: np.max(np.abs(p))
Out[18]: 1.0005162676670694
```

For a stable filter, that maximum must be less than 1. Unfortunately, the code doesn't warn you about this.

I suspect the problem is `b1`, not `b2`.  In the normalized units, you are trying to create a lower cutoff of 2.1e-4, which is pretty small.  If, for example, the lower cutoff is `200.0/nyq`, the filter is stable:

```
In [13]: b, a = signal.butter(5, [200.0 / nyq, 20000.0 / nyq], btype='band')

In [14]: z, p, k = signal.tf2zpk(b, a)

In [15]: np.max(np.abs(p))
Out[15]: 0.99601892668982284
```

Instead of using the `(b, a)` format for the filter, you can use the more robust `sos` (second order sections) format, which was added to scipy version 0.16.  To use it, change these two lines

```
b, a = signal.butter(5, [20.0 / nyq, 20000.0 / nyq], btype='band')
x = signal.lfilter(b, a, x)
```

to

```
sos = signal.butter(5, [20.0 / nyq, 20000.0 / nyq], btype='band', output='sos')
x = signal.sosfilt(sos, x)
```

That SOS filter does not suffer from the instability problem.

Comment: Thanks! We should add a [warning notice here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.butter.html) about unstability, because it's not mentioned. Something else: how do you know that we should use `sos`? It sounds like magical to me :) `sos` is not documented here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.butter.html. Is it similar to `zpk`?

Comment: Btw, I chose Butterworth completely at random, which solution would you use yourself to filter everything outside 20 - 20000Hz? I started a DSP.se question here: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/36564/filtering-everything-outside-20-20000-hz

Comment: *"sos is not documented here: [...]"*  You gave a link to the documentation for scipy 0.14.  The first SOS code was added to scipy in version 0.16.

Comment: The DSP stackexchange is the right place for the question of which filter to use, and it looks like you've already received one good answer.

Comment: Thanks, you're right I found it now in the Scipy 0.16 doc. And by the way, your Buttwerworth sos filter solution works well!