# Apply a filter on an audio sample with python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, audio, scipy

I'm trying to migrate my *Matlab* code over *Python*, but I'm having some troubles with filtering functions.

Here's the context :

I created a butterworth filter by calling the following function (*fc* is the bandpass center frequency, *q* its quality factor and *n* its order) :

```
def bandpass(fc, q, n):
    bw = fc / q
    low = fc - bw/2
    high = fc + bw/2
    return butter(N=n, Wn=[low, high], btype='band', analog=True)
```

And I have retrieved data from an audio signal (mono, sampled at *fs* = 48000, on 16-bits integers). Both are giving what I'm expecting when I plot the frequency response of the filter or the amplitude spectrum of the audio sample.

Here's the code :

```
# Imports
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.io.wavfile as sw
from scipy import signal
from scipy.signal import butter, lfilter

# Read audio file
fs, y = sw.read(file)
# Nb of samples and time scale
N = len(y)
t = np.linspace(0, N/fs, N)
# Plot amplitude spectrum
plt.plot(t, y/max(y))

# Filter creation
b, a = bandpass(1000, 5, 2)
w, h = signal.freqs(b, a, np.logspace(0, 5, 20000))
# Plot frequential response
plt.semilogx(w, 20 * np.log10(abs(h)));

# Apply filter on audio signal
lfilter(b, a, y) # < Give unexepected results
```

Then comes the part in which I'm stuck : I'm trying to apply the butterworth filter on the audio sample but it doesn't seem to work as the filtered signal diverge towards infinity and eventually end up in *NaN* values for an unknown reason. I assume that I missed a step despite following the docs. I also tried *filtfilt()* because it appeared in some researchs I did but it didn't work either.

Here's the [expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRK57.png) I got with Matlab which I'm trying to replicate.

What am I missing ?

Thanks for your answers :)

---

Bonus question : How can I can achieve to plot this [3d view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXucT.png) (`view(-45,65)` in Matlab) ?

Comment: I've never worked on something like this, but I checked the docs and `lfilter` does not work in-place. Therefore, `lfilter(b, a, y)` doesn't do anything; the results of that function are being thrown away because you don't assign them back to something e.g. `something = lfilter(b, a, y)`

Comment: Show the whole code, including imports. Also, don't know if it's an error or typo (most likely the second) there is a missing ] in your return function.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't specified it but I actually save the results (that's why I know that it ends up with *NaN*, it looks like : `array([-1.10000000e+05, 1.54463492e+07, 5.65446349e+08, ..., nan, nan, nan])`, but since the data isn't correct I can't plot it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a sampled (i.e. discrete-time) signal.  To filter it, you must use a discrete filter, so the `analog` argument of [`butter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.butter.html) must be `False` (which is the default).

To analyze the frequency response of the digital filter, use [`freqz`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.freqz.html), not `freqs`.

See [How to implement band-pass Butterworth filter with Scipy.signal.butter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093594/how-to-implement-band-pass-butterworth-filter-with-scipy-signal-butter/12233959#12233959) for a related question and answer regarding a bandpass filter.