# Implementing Butterworth bandpass filter running into: "ValueError: object of too small depth for desired array" error when using scipy.signal.lfilter

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, computer-vision, valueerror

I'm trying to implement Eulerian Video magnification as per [this](http://people.csail.mit.edu/mrub/papers/vidmag.pdf) paper, but when utilising the Butterworth bandpass filter, it keeps running into a "ValueError: object of too small depth for desired array"

This is my code for the Butterworth bandpass filter:

```
def butter_bandpass_filter(data, lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
    b, a = butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=order)
    y = scipy.signal.lfilter([b], [a], data, axis=0)     #The line that errors
    return y

def butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    low = lowcut / nyq
    high = highcut / nyq
    b, a = scipy.signal.butter(order, [low, high], btype='band')
    return b, a
```

I'm using the butter_bandpass_filter in the following line of code:

```
magnify_motion(tired_me, 0.4, 3)
def magnify_motion(video, low, high, n=4, sigma=3, amp=20):
    lap_video_lst = video.get_laplacian_lst(n=n, sigma=sigma)

    print("lap_video_lst shapes:")
    for i in range(n):
        print("{}:".format(i), get_list_shape(lap_video_lst[i]))

    ret_lst = []
    for layer in range(n):
        filtered_layer = butter_bandpass_filter(lap_video_lst[layer], low, high, video.fps)     #This line
        filtered_layer *= amp
        ret_lst.append(filtered_layer)

    return ret_lst
```

Where each lap_video_lst[layer] is formatted as a numpy array of all the frames of the video with shape (frame_count, height, width, colour_channels), and are as follows when printed:

```
0: (330, 360, 640, 3)
1: (330, 180, 320, 3)
2: (330, 90, 160, 3)
3: (330, 45, 80, 3)
```

Note that the reason each "layer" is of different dimensions is that they are the Laplacian pyramid of the original video.

In case it is useful, I This is the shape of the b and a np array, along with their respective values.

```
b: (1, 11)
[[ 0.00069339  0.         -0.00346694  0.          0.00693387  0.
  -0.00693387  0.          0.00346694  0.         -0.00069339]]
a: (1, 11)
[[  1.          -8.02213491  29.18702261 -63.4764537   91.44299881
  -91.21397148  63.81766134 -30.92689236   9.93534351  -1.91057439
  0.16700076]]
```

This is the full error trace in case there's some detail there that I'm overlooking:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Desktop\Stuff\Uni notes B\2021 Fall\Cs194\Projects\Project Final 1\tester.py", line 84, in <module>
    main()
  File "d:\Desktop\Stuff\Uni notes B\2021 Fall\Cs194\Projects\Project Final 1\tester.py", line 71, in main
    magnify_motion(tired_me, 0.4, 3)
  File "d:\Desktop\Stuff\Uni notes B\2021 Fall\Cs194\Projects\Project Final 1\tester.py", line 32, in magnify_motion
    filtered_layer = butter_bandpass_filter(lap_video_lst[layer], low, high, video.fps)
  File "d:\Desktop\Stuff\Uni notes B\2021 Fall\Cs194\Projects\Project Final 1\tester.py", line 17, in butter_bandpass_filter
    y = scipy.signal.lfilter([b], [a], data, axis=0)
  File "C:\Users\nick-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\scipy\signal\signaltools.py", line 1972, in lfilter
    raise ValueError('object of too small depth for desired array')
ValueError: object of too small depth for desired array
```

Any tips would be helpful! Thanks :D

UPDATE:
The reason I am using the square brackets around "b" and "a" is because I will get the following error without it, and I was told that's how I should fix this problem

```
ValueError: could not convert b, a, and x to a common type
```

Comment: *"This is my code for the Butterworth bandpass filter:..."*  That looks similar to my old code (from 2012): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093594/how-to-implement-band-pass-butterworth-filter-with-scipy-signal-butter/12233959#12233959.  But why have you put extra brackets around `b` and `a` in the call of `lfilter`?

Comment: The squarebrackets were to prevent the following Valuerror; "ValueError: could not convert b, a, and x to a common type" Not sure why it occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I am not reading the paper.

The problem you are seeing is fixed by applying

```py
y = scipy.signal.lfilter(b, a, data, axis=0)
```

This means that the filter will treat each array `data[:,x,y,c]` as a signal, filtering the value of each pixel, probably making the video to have some motion blur, different from spatial filtering that is used to make edges sharper or smoother. For spatial filtering you would use `axis=1` or `axis=2`.

This is an example that applies the filter to a black screen video.

```py
def butter_bandpass_filter(data, lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
    b, a = butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=order)
    y = scipy.signal.lfilter([b], [a], data, axis=0)     #The line that errors
    return y

def butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    low = lowcut / nyq
    high = highcut / nyq
    b, a = scipy.signal.butter(order, [low, high], btype='band')
    return b, a

# is reasonable to expect that image data will be uint8
data = np.zeros((330, 360, 640, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
b,a = butter_bandpass(0.1, 0.4, 200)
y = scipy.signal.lfilter(b, a, data)
```

Comment: I added the square brackets because I would otherwise get an "ValueError: could not convert b, a, and x to a common type" error, and another stack overflow post said that this was how you fix it.

Comment: So probably your video data is something different than simply a 3D array of a numeric tyipe. What is the answer (curious about the context).